# Are In App Purchases charged for people running the beta AFTER I've stopped the beta test (selected Not Available For Testing)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, testflight

My App is about to be released in the App Store. I have about 100 external beta testers using the latest beta build, which is also the build that will be released to the store.

Now I'm going to stop beta test by selecting 'Not Available For Testing' in iTunesConnect. The message that appears says that this will not affect the people who already have the build installed (it only prevents testers from installing any more builds). So I'm assuming they can continue using the beta version until it expires (57 more days in this case)

So now my question is. If these people do In App Purchases with the beta build, will it be charged? Or, will it not be charged (like normal for beta builds while test is in progress)?

Comment: They can no longer use the app, so they cannot pay for IAPs.

Comment: @Oddie. They can still use the App after I stop the beta test. You just prevent the beta testers from installing it. The ones that already installed before I stop the test can continue using it until the expiration date. Hence my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All beta testers will be able to get IAP for free as long as they have the beta installed on their device, so until the beta expire. What you can do is create IAP for beta and then delete/disable them once you have finish with it.

Comment: Tx. That confirms my assumption. Good suggestion on creating special IAPs for beta. Thanks

Comment: Yep ;) also, sometimes it's good to let beta testers having IAP for free. They helped you to improve your app

Comment: Yes. :-) Already gave them credits and premium through my server. Just wanted to know if they would be able to 'buy' even more for free. Thanks man!

Comment: By the way, if it is correct answer, consider accepting it ;)